# VS2010 "Framework and References" vs "Linker > Input"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, linker

When going through the ["Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Static Library (C++)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) they are referencing the static library through "References" under

```
"Project Properties >  Common Properties > Framework and References > Add New Reference"
```

Is this just a convenient way to link libraries that are in the same solution file? You could do the same process by pointing to the library through the Linker Options?

```
"Project Properties > Linker > General & Input
```

So the question is, is there any difference in the linking process?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is different from using Linker + Input, beyond being a lot more "visual" and less error-prone, it also affects the build order of projects.  In a good way, this ensures that the static lib project is built before the client project, as necessary.

VS supports parallel builds and will start multiple builds concurrently if there is no dependency between the projects.  Which can fail if there actually is one and a dependent project builds a bit slower.  There's another way to affect build order explicitly, Project + Project Dependencies.  Only necessary if VS can't figure it out by itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this was clear for me that References ensure, that certain libraries are built before the app, i rather ask if the process between both concepts are the same? So are References and Linker Inputs doing the same thing?

Comment: Yeah sure, it just adds the build output to the linker command in both cases, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2):

One **huge** setback of VS2010 “Framework and References” : ***It is a solution property*** even if it written inside the project file (`vcxproj`). Only references added in the solution will be resolved. From my experience, when you need to share a project between solutions, strange linking errors start to pop-up. Most of the time missing references, which may be from a difference config (a 64 bit compilation which worked fine saying a 32 bit dependency is missing - guaranteed "wtf??" ).

So if you have a project with 3 references in in solution A, to add that project in solution B you also need to add those 3 referenced projects as it was on A, set the 3 references as it was on A and get all the overhead of having 3 additional projects in your solution compared to linking to a specific library.

Comment: I agree that linker + input should be preferred over "Frameworks and References" when a project is linked in multiple solutions.  I am currently going through the pain of splitting up a 170 project solution into two, and I really wish nobody had ever used "Frameworks and References".